# jQuery Tools | overlay position relative to body and not the browser window

Tags: jquery, position, overlay

I have a problem with the position of my overlay. I might be using the wrong methood for all I know, but here's my situation:

I wanted an overlay to show up at a specific location on my page.
I got that to work with jQuery Tools Overlay (http://jquerytools.org/).

- Here's a link to my site : http://www.kiledesign.no

And here's my js-code for the overlay so far:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.brick_index[rel]").overlay({fixed:false,top:282,mask {color:'#000',opacity:0.50},closeOnClick:true});
});
```

Now the `overlay` opens `282px` from the top - relative to the window, and not relative to the `body` - which is the problem. (the `fixed:false`-part of the code makes sure the overlay keeps the position after it's opened when you scroll the page ).

Everything works great when you're at the very top of the page. The `overlay` opens exactly where I want it to be opened - covering the "bricks" right next to the red "brick".
But immediately you scroll down a bit and then clicks the `overlay`-triggers, the `overlay` still position itself `282px` down from the top of the window. That's not what I wanted.

- Here's a link to my site again: http://www.kiledesign.no

Anyone know how I can get this to work the way I want?

*The text content is in Norwegian*

*I've looked at this : [JqueryTools overlay position based on window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575800/jquerytools-overlay-position-based-on-window-size) but couldn't figure out how to use, and where to put, the suggested code. And the link to the solution didn't work.*

Answer (score 1):

After a bit back and forth have I finally figured out how to make this work.

By just changing `top:282` to `top:top` in the js-code - the position of the overlay places it self to the top of parent element. I didn't know that, and I can't remember having seen this in the documentation either...